# placement of icon in center failed

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

i would like to place MDIcon in center of the screen,  i  read the documentation and followed videos  and try folowing code :

```
`from kivymd.app import  MDApp
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel
from kivymd.uix.label import MDIcon
class MyApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        # mylabel =MDLabel(text="Hello here",halign="center",theme_text_color='Custom',
        #                  text_color=(0,0,1,1),font_style="H1")
        icon_label =MDIcon(icon='language-python',halign='center')
        return icon_label

MyApp().run()`
```

but when i am running the code, i  am getting following result :
[image: mdicon]

i am really surprised, because previous command

```
` # mylabel =MDLabel(text="Hello here",halign="center",theme_text_color='Custom',
        #                  text_color=(0,0,1,1),font_style="H1")`
```

was working fine, so  what should be  a reason for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `MDLabel` looks centered because it fills the window. The `MDIcon` sets its own size to the size of the icon, so it gets positioned at the default position of (0, 0) (as does the `MDLabel`), but since it does not fill the window, it ends up in the bottom left corner. The fix is to position the `MDIcon` using position hints, like this:

```
icon_label =MDIcon(icon='language-python',halign='center', pos_hint={'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5})
```